# SQL Server Import - Weird number

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I've imported some data into SQL server using the data import/export tool.

I'm exporting from a .xls workbook to SQL Server 2012.

The issue is that two fields, containing large(ish) numbers have been imported in a weird format.

**Original Data:**

```
532842549
```

**What SQL Server Shows (Or Similar)**

```
1.8327e+006
```

So far I have tried formatting the cells in excel to text, number + general but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way I can cast this value directly in SQL server back to the original value?

The destination field is a varchar(50) field.

Comment: If the destination field is a varchar(50), try changing the format of the columns in Excel to text before you import.

Comment: It says in the question I've already tried that.

Comment: Does each cell show a ' in front of the text?

Comment: What does the import tool say the data type of the source column is?

Comment: Float, but I can't seem to get that to change.

Comment: You could save the Excel file as a csv, after which you would be able to change the source data type.  Or you can import to a staging table where the columns will be set as a number data type, then insert to your destination table from that staging table with the appropriate `Cast fieldname as Varchar(50)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried exporting `Excel` data to `MSSQL Server` and it went smooth. See the following steps.

1. Created a file with following data.

[image]

2. Went to `MSSQL Server` and started Imported Data. `Right Click on Database` => `Tasks` => `Import Data ...`
3. On `column mappings step` of conversion wizard, I changed type to `bigint`.

[image]

4. It's done. Check the final output.

[image]